# low resolution in R ggplot2 plots with transparent background on Shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, transparency

I am facing a problem when adding transparency to the `ggplot2` plots. I am losing resolution of the tickmark and axis labels. Below is what is happening :

I have imported "cyborg" bootstrap theme from [here](https://bootswatch.com/cyborg/). Hence I believe the problem arise due to this them color not matching with the plot bg.

[image]

Code :

```
# to exhibit low resolution plots

# Global variables can go here
library(shiny)
waterfall_data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:6,
  factors = letters[1:6],
  values = c(1:6)
)
waterfall_data$factors <- factor(waterfall_data$factors, levels = letters[1:6])
waterfall_data$end <- cumsum(waterfall_data$values)
waterfall_data$start <- c(0, head(waterfall_data$end, -1))
waterfall_data$end <- c(head(waterfall_data$end, -1), 0)


# Define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap_cyborg.css",
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(

                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    plotOutput('plot')  
                  )
                )
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot <- ggplot(waterfall_data, aes(factors)) + 
      geom_rect(aes(x = factors, ymin = end, ymax = start, xmin = id-0.45, xmax = id+0.45 ),
                fill = 'darkgreen')+
      xlab(label = "columns")+
      ylab(label = "value")+
      geom_text(aes(label = values, y = end),vjust=-0.5)+   
      theme(
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent") # bg of the panel
        , plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent") # bg of the plot
        , panel.grid.major = element_blank() # get rid of major grid
        , panel.grid.minor = element_blank() # get rid of minor grid
        , legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent") # get rid of legend bg
        , legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent") # get rid of legend panel bg
      )
    print(plot)
  }, bg="transparent")
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there a way to use this theme and also have plot labels clear?

Comment: Are you exporting the plot somewhere or saving it somehow? Are you just talking about the resolution in the RGUI built in image viewer?

Comment: Do the labels display correctly if you delete the `theme` part?

Comment: Not to mention the reproducible example as usual: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @joel.wilson, please post the essential Shiny code that reproduces this issue.

Comment: @m-dz  - I have attached the code. Would you be able to help now?

Comment: @Mako212 - if i ignore `theme()` then bckground would be white and yes the labels will be clearer. The low resolution is happening once I bring it to the bootstrap_cyborg.css bg.

Comment: @joel.wilson, not without `bootstrap_cyborg.css` I am afraid...

Comment: @m-dz here is the link to that file : [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsgYo_piiIWJjDZHLv0Lg4sgNF9N)