# R Shiny plot transparent background: low resolution (white pixels around axis text and labels, and title)

Tags: r, shiny, transparent

I am trying to make an app with transparent plots on different background colors. The problem is that text on the plots looks very low resolution.

The same question has been asked [low resolution in R ggplot2 plots with transparent background on Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46917949/8097192) but with no MRE and is not answered.

Here is an MRE:

```
library(shiny)

transparent_theme = theme_bw(20) + theme(
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"), 
  plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA), 
  panel.grid = element_blank(),
  panel.border = element_blank(),
  axis.line = element_line()
)


ui = fluidPage(
  tags$style('.container-fluid { background-color: #007BA7;}'),
  plotOutput("test")
)

server = function(input, output){
  output$test = renderPlot({

    X = data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)

    ggplot(X, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point(size=5) + ggtitle("Test") +
      transparent_theme


  }, bg = "transparent") 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```